# Missing project structure when importing files to intellij

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

It seems after importing the project file, the build is successful as shown:
[[image: successful build]

but i am unable to run as it would always ask me to edit my run/debug configurations whereas my friend is able to run his. Below is the comparison between mine and his.
[[image: Mine] [[image: His]

It also seems that there are some configurations such as artifacts present on his project structure but mine is empty which could be the reason why..but why?

i am using windows and my friend is using mac

Comment: You may need to configure the modules. Sometimes it has issues finding them. Open Project Structure and import the maven/gradle modules or reimport.

Comment: find that Application class and right-click to run/debug it. then the configuration will appear in the list.

Comment: Did you import build.gradle file or *.iml?

Comment: You probably imported the project in a different way. I would recommend to just use the "edit run/debug configurations", copy the configuration from your friend and continue from that point.